# Retornar três valores diferentes entre duas tabelas que não possuem relacionamento no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, modelo-relacional

Tenho um banco de dados com 3 tabelas, em que os relacionamentos e atributos estão distribuídos dessa forma: [image: Diagrama]

Preciso `Retornar o nome, data de nascimento e número do cartão das pessoas em ordem decrescente pela idade;`

Mas como eu posso retornar valores entre tabelas que não possuem relacionamento? No caso a tabela `pessoas` e a tabela `cartoes`.

Comment: Utilize a tabela contas para os joins, mesmo que não vá retornar nenhum dela no select final.

Comment: `select pessoas.nome, pessoas.data, contas.id_conta from pessoas inner join contas on pessoas.id_pessoa = contas.pessoas_id_pessoa; `

Dessa forma?

Comment: @mateus-medeiros O seu caso se resolve com um simples `INNER JOIN`, já tentou efetuar o seguinte `select`: `SELECT pessoa.nome, pessoa.data, cartao.numero FROM pessoas AS pessoa INNER JOIN contas AS conta ON conta.id_conta = pessoa.id_pessoa INNER JOIN cartoes AS cartao ON cartao.id_conta = conta.id_conta`

Comment: deu certo, @William, obrigado! só uma dúvida, um usuário possui dois cartões, mas só retornou um, será que há algum problema?

Comment: @mateus-medeiros acho que a modelagem da tabelas não estão tão corretas assim, veja se esse exemplo te ajuda. [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c02a51/2)

Comment: de fato @William, vou dar uma olhada nesse exemplo e tentar aplicar ao meu problema, obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu caso se resolve com um simples `INNER JOIN`, já tentou efetuar o seguinte `select`:

```
SELECT 
    pessoa.nome, 
    pessoa.data, 
    cartao.numero 
FROM 
    pessoas AS pessoa 
INNER JOIN 
    contas AS conta ON conta.id_conta = pessoa.id_pessoa 
INNER JOIN 
    cartoes AS cartao ON cartao.id_conta = conta.id_conta
```